# Set not setting in CMD batch script

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I'm trying to write a script that will find all directory junctions on a disk and then recreate them in another location. First of all, I have to find all the junctions and edit the output to be more readable.

This is the test.txt:

```
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is A0D2-DFB0

 Directory of C:\

14.07.2009.  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
13.01.2015.  10:26    <JUNCTION>     Users [E:\Users]
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\ProgramData

14.07.2009.  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Application Data [C:\ProgramData]
14.07.2009.  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Desktop [C:\Users\Public\Desktop]
14.07.2009.  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Documents [C:\Users\Public\Documents]
14.07.2009.  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Favorites [C:\Users\Public\Favorites]
14.07.2009.  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Start Menu [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu]
14.07.2009.  06:08    <JUNCTION>     Templates [C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Templates]
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath

24.12.2014.  18:22    <SYMLINK>      java.exe [D:\Programs\Java 8u25\bin\java.exe]
24.12.2014.  18:22    <SYMLINK>      javaw.exe [D:\Programs\Java 8u25\bin\javaw.exe]
24.12.2014.  18:22    <SYMLINK>      javaws.exe [D:\Programs\Java 8u25\bin\javaws.exe]
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               8 Dir(s)  16.309.276.672 bytes free
```

-
This is the (unfinished) script that I'm running:

```
echo on

cd \

set start=
set end=
set paths=

type NUL > output.txt

for /f "tokens=* skip=3" %%l in (C:\test.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=1" %%d in ("%%l") do (
 if %%d==Directory (
    for /f "tokens=3" %%p in ("%%l") do (
      set start="%%p"
    )
 ) else (
   for /f "tokens=3" %%j in ("%%l") do (
      if %%j==^<JUNCTION^> (
          for /f "tokens=4*" %%h in ("%%l") do (
            set end="%%h"
            echo %start% %end% >> output.txt

          )
       )
    )
 )
)
)
```

Problem is that output.txt ends up with several lines of "Echo is ON" instead of having paths in there. If I substitute "%start% %end%" with any string (eg. "sausage") I get output.txt filled with sausages. If I run echo set %end% after the script runs, output is "Templates" which is expected. I'm guessing that set command doesn't set anything until one of the loops is done.

Am I right? Is there a way around that? I really need to get this working in CMD because it has to be run from Windows Repair disk.

P.S. I know my code won't work for my purpose even with this program fixed, but I'm just getting there, first things first.

Comment: set does not work in ( ) because a batch file is not actually processed in that order. Basically the entire script without code between ( ) is exeucted, and then the part between ( ) is executed. You can overcome this by writing the second code in a second batch file and execute that in your FOR statement. The first one, you can place the set line entirely on the FOR line and remove the ( ) all together.

Comment: also, to ommit the other ( ), use goto variable and :variable.

Comment: @LPChip - your solution can work, but not for the reason you state.

Comment: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/ln/ln.html

Comment: @dbenham by all means enlighten us why you say so. I found out that when I have scripts like this, the SET command always has the last variable set in the loop, so I assumed it isn't processed in actual order.

Comment: @STTR ln is for linux, not windows.

Comment: @LPChip see end page - download ln.exe ...

Comment: @LPChip - The SET works just fine - it is the variable expansion that is not giving what you want. Search and read about batch file delayed expansion. This issue comes up multiple times every week at StackOverflow, and occasionally here at SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use your original script and add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` you can replace `%start%` and `%end%` by `!start!` and `!end!` and your script will work as you intended.

Your script doesn't allow for blanks in the file names, so I propose the following modified script:-

```
echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

cd \

set start=
set end=
set paths=

type NUL > output.txt

for /f "tokens=* skip=3" %%l in (C:\test.txt) do ^
for /f "tokens=1-2*" %%d in ("%%l") do ^
if %%d==Directory (
    set start="%%f"
) else (
    for /f "tokens=3*" %%j in ("%%l") do ^
if %%j==^<JUNCTION^> (
            for /f "tokens=1 delims=[" %%n in ("%%k") do set end=%%n
            set end="!end:~0,-1!"
            echo !start! !end! >> output.txt

        )
)
```

I have done two additional things here:-

1. I have removed brackets from the commands that do not need it (unfortunately, the new line after the continuation character `^` cannot be indented, which spoils the formatting of the second `if`).
2. I have removed unnecessary `for` loops while at the same time allowing for embedded blanks in the directory and file names.

I have left them in, but the initial `cd \`  and `set` initialisations are unnecessary, though you may wish to clear `start` and `end` before exiting.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `echo %start% %end% >> output.txt` with `call :forecho` and attach next code snippet beneath the last script line:

```
goto :eof

:forecho
    echo %start% %end% >> output.txt
goto :eof
```

Problem lays in fact that %variables% are expanded, command by command, at parse time rather than at execution time. And all code snippet enclosed in `(`parenthheses`)` is considered to be an only command.

To be on the safe side, start your script with

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
```

Whole script then could be as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
cd \
set start=
set end=
set paths=
type NUL > output.txt

for /f "tokens=* skip=3" %%l in (C:\test.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=1" %%d in ("%%l") do (
 if %%d==Directory (
    for /f "tokens=3" %%p in ("%%l") do (
      set start="%%p"
    )
 ) else (
   for /f "tokens=3" %%j in ("%%l") do (
      if %%j==^<JUNCTION^> (
          for /f "tokens=4*" %%h in ("%%l") do (
            set end="%%h"
            call :forecho
          )
       )
    )
 )
)
)
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:forecho
    echo %start% %end% >> output.txt
goto :eof
```